# Zoomooz js plugin [Firefox issue]

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, jquery-plugins, zoomooz

I am trying to implement an animation on click in the following fiddle:
[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LA6VW/40/)

```
   var animating = false;

    rotateDoor = function() {
        if (animating)
            return;
        var door = $('#door');
        animating = true;
        openDoor(door, 5);

    };

    openDoor = function(door, angle) {
        if (angle >= 90) {
            animating = false;
            return;
        }
        door.css('-webkit-transform', 'perspective(200px) rotateY( ' + angle + 'deg )');
        door.css('-moz-transform', 'perspective(200px) rotateY( ' + angle + 'deg )');
        setTimeout(function() {
            openDoor(door, angle += 1);
        }, 20);
    };
});
```

I have added the Zoomooz js plugin externally in the fiddle and there seems to some lag issue in the animation ***after the door has closed***.*(Only in firefox.)*

My firefox version is 26.0,Mozilla Firefox for ubuntu canonical 1.0

**Update**:Its not a door issue alone,firefox picks up Zoomooz and is very slow in firefox.

Comment: Hi I know you asked this question more than a year ago, but your fiddle looks fine in Firefox 38.0.5 so probably they improved something after you posted this question. I'm having a performance issue with zoomooz.js in Firefox too, did you find a workaround for your problem?

Comment: @TonyJmnz I dont remember what i did exactly, but this was the final product. http://www.egggeo.com/kids-corner/